# POST audio to a network camera

Tags: post, audio, curl, ip-camera

I have a few SerComm IP cameras (RC8221, RC8230, OC821D).  All three of them have built in speakers and, according to their API, will play audio which is POSTed to them.

The documentation says....

> Audio Upload (uploading audio streaming to the camera)
>
> Method: POST
>
> URL: http://[ip]/img/g726.cgi G.726 audio stream (16Kbps or 32Kbps,
>
> URL: http://[ip]/img/g711a.cgi G.711 a-law audio stream (64Kbps)
>
> URL: http://[ip]/img/g711u.cgi G.711 u-law audio stream (64Kbps)
>
> Example (client side):
>
> POST /IMG/g726.cgi HTTP/1.0\r\n
>
> Host: 192.168.0.99\r\n
>
> Return:
>
> OK
>
> HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n
>
> Client starts to upload the audio stream.

I have some a-law and u-law G.711 files I've created in Audacity.  Mplayer confirms their spec.

I'm trying to POST the audio using

```
curl -vv -F "file=@alaw8ktest.wav;type=audio/wav" -A "Mozilla/5.0" http://user:pass@192.168.0.42/img/g711a.cgi
```

However, no sound comes out of the cameras.  The response I get back is

```
* About to connect() to 192.168.0.42 port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.0.42... connected
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user'
> POST /img/g711a.cgi HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic abc123==
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
> Host: 192.168.0.42
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 18940
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------68ffb6462b1c
>
```

After a minute or so, the following is returned.

```
* Done waiting for 100-continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Status: 200 OK
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 30 Oct 2013 15:21:14 GMT
< Server: ip-camera
< 
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.0.42 left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

I've tried various things - changing the UA, posting the audio to different URLs, not including MIME types.  Nothing seems to work.  I've ensured that the speaker is set to "on" in the admin interface and the volume is set to loud.

So - does anyone have any ideas on how to craft the CURL request to work?  I'm sure it's something obvious :-)

Comment: I've also tried adding -0 to force curl to use HTTP1.0, but the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

This works for my Sercomm RC8021 camera :-

```
curl -vv --data-binary @testcam.wav http://192.168.1.195/img/g711a.cgi
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please could you share a copy of the wav file? The above command doesn't seem to work for me - but now I'm wondering if it's my audio file.

Comment: This also worked for me. Although, I'm not fluent enough with audio files to know any better and the classical music .wav I tested it with became an incredibly loud alien transmission blaring into my earphones.

Comment: After properly converting my file I've been successfully using this to play some sounds on my camera, but it cuts off after 1 second playing. Are you still looking for a wav file to test it with?

Answer (score 0):

Try chmod your sound file to 755, or if that doesn't work, do a 777 (which is a risk to the security of your file, but its just sound file right?)

What could have happened could be that the connection and the delivery of the file worked perfectly, but when the camera tries to save the file, its access to do so may be denied by the permissions of your sound file.

Comment: Looks appropriate for comment rather than answer.

Comment: Will try that tonight... Odd, but will be fun if it works :-)